# Python - BeautifulSoup: Where is the doc on .select and .get method?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am looking for the documentation regarding the methods `.select` and `.get` for BeautifulSoup.

Weirdly enough the docu website debates at length uncommon methods such as `.find_next_sibling` etc. but seems to not explain the above-mentionned methods?

https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.select()` method is documented under the [CSS selectors](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) chapter. `BeautifulSoup` supports a limited set of CSS selectors, but they still cover most common use cases. There is also `.select_one()` to get a single element match.

The `.get()` method itself is not a part of `BeautifulSoup` API. It is usually used in the context of getting an attribute value when a [`Tag` is treated as a dictionary](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#attributes):

```
elm = soup.find("elm", class_="myclass")
print(elm.get("class"))
```